# Managing Processes from Python multiprocessing module

Tags: python, multiprocessing

So I thought I'd finally post; what is the proper way to manage `Process` workers? I've tried to use a `Pool`, but I noticed I could not get the return value of each completed process. I tried to use a callback but that didn't work as expected either. Should I just be managing them myself with `active_children ()`?

My Pool code:

```
from multiprocessing import *                                                                                      
import time
import random

SOME_LIST = []

def myfunc():
    a = random.randint(0,3)
    time.sleep(a)
    return a

def cb(retval):
    SOME_LIST.append(retval)

print("Starting...")

p = Pool(processes=8)
p.apply_async(myfunc, callback=cb)
p.close()
p.join()

print("Stopping...")
print(SOME_LIST)
```

I expect a list of values; but all I get is the last item in the worker job to complete:

```
$ python multi.py 
Starting...
Stopping...
[3]
```

Note: The answer should not use `threading` module; here is the reason why:

> In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can
>   execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented
>   libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your
>   application to make better use of the computational resources of
>   multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing.

Comment: Using a `Pool` is the correct way. You should be able to get the return value of each completed worker `Process`, too : `return_value = pool.apply(func, args=(arg1, arg2)`. Can you share the code you're trying to use that isn't working?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but this works fine, too: `return_value = pool.apply(func)`. Where `func` is `def func(): return 12345`. `return_value` will be assigned to the `12345` returned by `func`.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you expect a list of results from the above example? You're just calling `apply_async` once, which means you're just calling `myfunc` a single time in one of the worker processes. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Nope. It just calls it once. To call it for every process in the pool, you'd need to do `for _ in range(pool._processes): pool.apply_async(myfunc, callback=cb)`. Or, if you make `myfunc` take a single argument (which you could ignore), you could do: `SOME_LIST = pool.map(myfunc, range(pool._processes))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the way `apply_async` works. It doesn't call the function you pass to it in every process in the `Pool`. It just calls the function one time, in one of the worker processes. So the results you're seeing are to be expected. You have a couple of options to get the behavior you want:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool                                                                                   
import time
import random

SOME_LIST = []

def myfunc():
    a = random.randint(0,3)
    time.sleep(a)
    return a

def cb(retval):
    SOME_LIST.append(retval)

print("Starting...")

p = Pool(processes=8)
for _ in range(p._processes):
    p.apply_async(myfunc, callback=cb)
p.close()
p.join()

print("Stopping...")
print(SOME_LIST)
```

Or

```
from multiprocessing import Pool                                                                                      
import time
import random


def myfunc():
    a = random.randint(0,3)
    time.sleep(a)
    return a

print("Starting...")

p = Pool(processes=8)
SOME_LIST = p.map(myfunc, range(p._processes))
p.close()
p.join()

print("Stopping...")
print(SOME_LIST)
```

Note that you could also call `apply_async` or `map` for *more* than the number of processes in the pool. The idea of the `Pool` is that it guarantees exactly `num_processes` processes will be running for the entire lifetime of the `Pool`, no matter how many tasks you submit. So if you create a `Pool(8)` and call `apply_async` once, one of your eight workers will get a task, and the other seven will be idle. If you create a `Pool(8)` and call `apply_async` 80 times, the 80 tasks will get distributed to your eight workers, with no more than eight of the tasks actually being processed at once.